# How to use a Controller method inside a service with dependency injection?

Tags: 8, dependency-injection, symfony-services

I'm using the [diff](https://www.drupal.org/project/diff) module for a project, this module has a method inside a Controller that I want to use in a service to reuse code. As this time I'm just calling the method like `PluginRevisionController::getRevisionIds()` but this give me the message:

> Deprecated function: Non-static method
> Drupal\diff\Controller\PluginRevisionController::getRevisionIds()
> should not be called statically

So, I want to 'inject' if possible in some way the Controller (I really don't know if this is possible) inside the service to reuse the logic. There is a way to do this?

Comment: Bad diff module design, that method should've been in a service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could inject a `ClassResolverInterface` or `ControllerResolverInterface` into your service to load a controller instance.

From core.services.yml:

```yml
controller_resolver:
  class: Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerResolver
  arguments: ['@psr7.http_message_factory', '@class_resolver']
class_resolver:
  class: Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ClassResolver
  calls:
    - [setContainer, ['@service_container']]
```

Both classes will return an instance, just the method names differ.

```php
$controller = $this->classResolver->getInstanceFromDefinition(PluginRevisionController::class);
$controller = $this->controllerResolver->getControllerFromDefinition(PluginRevisionController::class);
```